# The Terraform CLI get a Error: ID was missing the `slots` element

Tags: azure, runtime-error, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I am executing `terraform.exe apply` on windows and receive the error:

```
azurerm_subnet.subnet: Refreshing state... [id=<...>]
azurerm_app_service_plan.service_plan: Refreshing state... [id=<...>]
azurerm_app_service.app: Refreshing state... [id=<...>]
azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection.test: Refreshing state... [id=<...>]
azurerm_app_service_slot.production: Refreshing state... [id=<...>]
azurerm_app_service_slot.staging: Refreshing state... [id=<...>]

Error: ID was missing the `slots` element
```

I am attempting to build an Azure WebApp with different slots and docker images with terraform. It should deploy an Azure WebApp with different slots based on Dockerfile images.

The first run is without an error. I receive the error when I refresh the resources.

I am using azurerm provider version 2.1.0 and the azurerm backend.

See the following terraform file:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "..."
    storage_account_name = "..."
    container_name       = "..."
    key                  = "..."

    subscription_id      = "..."
    tenant_id            = "..."

    sas_token            = "...."
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~>2.1.0"
  features {}
}

variable "environment" {
  default = "production"
}
variable "resource_group" {}
variable "location" {
  default = "West Europe"
}
variable "app_name" {}
variable "network" {}
variable "subnet_prefix" {}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "service_plan" {
  name                = var.app_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group

  kind = "Linux"
  reserved = true

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
    Cost        = "€0,081/Stunde"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "app" {
  name                = var.app_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.service_plan.id
  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service_plan.service_plan]

  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|<...>.azurecr.io/<...>:0.0.1-95"
    always_on        = "true"
  }

  app_settings = {
    ...
  }

  storage_account {
    access_key = "..."
    account_name = "..."
    name = "certs"
    share_name = "certs"
    type = "AzureBlob"
    mount_path = "/var/certs"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_slot" "production" {
  name                = var.app_name
  app_service_name    = azurerm_app_service.app.name
  location            = azurerm_app_service.app.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.service_plan.id

  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service.app]

  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|<...>.azurecr.io/<...>:0.0.1-95"
    always_on        = "true"

  }

  app_settings = {
    "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_slot" "staging" {
  name                = "staging"
  app_service_name    = azurerm_app_service.app.name
  location            = azurerm_app_service.app.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.service_plan.id

  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service.app]

  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|<...>.azurecr.io/<...>:latest"
    always_on        = "true"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = var.app_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group
  virtual_network_name = var.network
  address_prefix       = var.subnet_prefix

  delegation {
    name = var.app_name

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/networkinterfaces/*",
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action",
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action",
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/unprepareNetworkPolicies/action"
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "test" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.app.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_app_service.app,
    azurerm_subnet.subnet
  ]
}
```

What does a missing slots element mean in this context?

Comment: Share the whole Terraform code, please.

Comment: You should also edit your question to include the full error output including the surrounding context that shows where the error is coming from.

Comment: Does this issue can be reproduced every time? To narrow down this issue, if you remove the `resource "azurerm_app_service_slot"` when terraform init, plan, apply, Is this issue still appearing? The configuration files looks correct.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this provider to be able to say exactly what's going on here, but this error seems to come from [the resource ID parsing in the Azure provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/8174fd51cada9a1fd982d2e7e9fe36a5d70ce2b1/azurerm/helpers/azure/resourceid.go#L97) and seems to mean that one of these resource instances is supposed to have an id containing a `/slots/...` portion. I'd run `terraform show` and look at the `id` of each instance to see if any of them look strange.

Answer (score 6):

Terraform treats resource identifiers as case sensitive, but azure doesn't.

Somewhere inside your state file you probably have an id like `/Slots/` instead of `/slots/`.

You can use `terraform state pull` and `terraform state push` to manually edit your state file I think. Usually not recommended, but TF validation insists on forcing case sensitivity while the azure portal itself will show you resource IDs with inconsistent capitalization :/